# Causal Inference where the treatment assignment is randomized

Tags: python, statistics, ab-test, causalimpact

I have mostly worked with Observational data where the treatment assignment was not randomized. In the past, I have used PSM, IPTW to balance and then calculate ATE.
My problem is:
Now I am working on a problem where the treatment assignment is randomized meaning there won't be a confounding effect. But treatment and control groups have different sizes. There's a bucket imbalance.

Now should I just analyze the data as it is and run statistical significance and Statistical power test?
Or shall I balance the imbalance of sizes between the treatment and control using let's say covariate matching and then run significance tests?

Comment: Please avoid asking the same question on [two sites](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/555346/250483) (cross-posting).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it been cross-posted on stats.SE